# How to run cesiumjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, configuration, cesiumjs

I followed some instructions,so cesium running locally

[image]

and then did hello world example like this

[image]

But I cannot see anything when i clicked open in browser. I failed constantly

[image]

I don't know what can i do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article [ask] about how to ask questions also read this article [mre] about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement. Good luck 

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  .

Comment: Please don't tag your IDE or code editor unless your question is specifically related to the editor itself.

Answer (score 0):

From your images, it looks like your Cesium development server is running on port 8080. However, your web browser is simply viewing the local HTML file through its filesystem path (`C:\Users\GSY\...`) and not through the server. You need to serve your HTML file through `http://localhost:8080/` and enter the path to the HTML file relative to where you started the server from. For example, if you started the server in `C:\Users\GSY\Desktop`, you should try URL `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/hello1.html`.

I have no idea what your filesystem setup actually is, so you'll need to adjust the URLs based on your system and where you installed things.

However, based on a very quick glance at the [Cesium JS quickstart](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs-learn/cesiumjs-quickstart/) page, you haven't set up your environment properly with an API token, and at any rate you haven't instructed the page to show anything, so it's not surprising the page is blank. I strongly suggest reading through the quickstart examples and looking at the [API documentation](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/) to understand how to use this tool.

Comment: Thank u. I succeed! But I'm very confused about what happend. I do nothing but just copied code from the first way(import from CDN), evne without start npm. However, I can preview on browser.

Comment: Thanks again Matt. I finally got it. Following your method, I changed my URL.